# Непонятные комментарии в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть код

```
    /**
 * Determine whether the user can view the post.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Post  $post
 * @return mixed
 */
public function view(User $user, Post $post)
{
    //
}
```

Для чего используется код в комментариях, можно ли это генерировать автоматически .

Если есть ссылки на эту тему буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это [PHPDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/). Он служит как для документации кода, так и для того, чтоб IDE лучше помогала работать с кодом (статический анализ).
Помимо документации кода PHPDoc умеет:

- Помечать виртуальные поля, чтоб они отображались в автодополнении (например для ActiveRecord)
- Указывать типы существующих полей, которые еще не определены (не особо актуально в последних версиях PHP)
- Указывать тип возвращаемого значения
- Некоторые ORM используют аннотации для связи между полями в БД и св-вами класса

На самом деле возможностей гораздо больше, это первое, что пришло на ум.

Обычно в IDE есть автоматическая генерация, например, в PHPStorm нужно над уже реализованной функцией/классом написать `/**` и нажать `Enter`.